How to get socat exit code when piping stdin to it?
I am executing commands against a docker container using socat and I want to get the exit code of the code executed in the container.
This is what I've tried:
$ docker run --rm -itd --name test123 ubuntu
$ echo "ls" | socat EXEC:"docker attach test123",pty - &> /dev/null
$ echo $?
0
$ echo "foobar" | socat EXEC:"docker attach test123",pty - &> /dev/null
$ echo $?
0

as you can see this is not working properly because the exit code for the foobar command should obviously be non-zero.
$ socat -V
socat version 1.8.0.1 on 
   running on Darwin version


@Kusalananda I think you're mistaken

You are correct, my apologies.  However, it seems as if you expect the exit status of the command running in the docker container to be propagated to the outside via socat.  Is that a correct assumption of what the issue is?  There obviously was no error running socat in either of your examples...

It seems to be primarily a question about how socat handles (or does not handle) the exit status of the command that it forks+execs when using EXEC.

@Kusalananda no worries. yes that's correct, that's what I'd like to achieve

@Kusalananda yes spot on

It might be worthwile adding that clarification into the question body ...

@AdminBee which clarification?

Socat propagates the exit code of EXEC'd commands:
$ socat EXEC:true,pty - &> /dev/null; echo $?
0
$ socat EXEC:false,pty - &> /dev/null; echo $?
1

So it is probably docker attach that does not give the expected exit code.

echo "foo" | socat EXEC:false,pty - &> /dev/null; echo $? returns zero though

On Ubuntu 20.04 and with /usr/bin/socat it returns 1, for me

man bash, in the VARIABLES section, shows what you need:
PIPESTATUS
An array variable (see Arrays) containing a list of exit status
values from the processes in the most-recently-executed
foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).


The exit status of a pipeline is that of the last command of the pipeline. In this case it's socat.
